# Using an if statement for a list of words

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

So I have a program (say, `programA`), that will give me an output, for example: `yes`, `no`, `maybe`, `probably`, `possibly`, `impossible`, `banana`.

I want to make a script that will do something, whatever it is, based on that output. Let's say I only need to account for `yes`, `maybe` and `banana`.

So far what I would do, is use `case` like so:

```bsh
case $program_output in
  yes) echo "good word: $program_output" ;;
  maybe) echo "good word: $program_output" ;;
  banana) echo "good word: $program_output" ;;
  *) echo "bad word: $program_output" ;;
esac
```

But recently I was fiddling with the `if` statement, and found out I can do this faster like so:

```bsh
if [[ "yesmaybebanana" =~ ${program_output} ]]; then
  echo "good word: ${program_output}"; else echo "bad word: ${program_output}";
fi
```

Is there any reason why I should not use the `if` statement for this?
This is a case where `$program_output` cannot have spaces in it, and it's a limited list of words it can output.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use `bash`'s regular expression functions (which however are `bash`-specific and therefore not portable), you should at least use the proper "OR"-type operator to enforce exact match with *one* of the allowed words, as in

```bsh
if [[ $program_output =~ ^(yes|maybe|banana)$ ]]
then
    echo "Good word: $program_output"
else
    echo "Bad word: $program_output"
fi
```

Notice that there must be no quotes around the regular expression, and that the word alternatives are enclosed between `^` and `$` anchors to ensure that no sub-string can trigger a match (such as `yessir` which would otherwise be caught by the pattern `yes`).

Answer (score 18):

The `if` version is not going to be as reliable as `case` here because it
will catch all substrings of `yesmaybebanana` - it will match for `b`,
`bebana` etc:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

program_output='bebana'

if [[ "yesmaybebanana" =~ ${program_output} ]]; then echo "good word: ${program_output}"; else echo "bad word: ${program_output}"; fi
```

Output:

```
good word: bebana
```

And it's not portable - try running it with dash:

```
$ dash ./a.sh
./a.sh: 6: ./a.sh: [[: not found
bad word: bebana
```

You can significantly simplify your `case` version by using multiple
words in a single line:

```
case $program_output in
  yes | maybe | banana) echo "good word: $program_output" ;;
  *) echo "bad word: $program_output" ;;
esac
```

Comment: "because it will catch all substrings of `yesmaybebanana`" -- as well as all matching regular expressions. If `program_output` is `.`, `.*`, `beba(na){2}`, `(foo bar)?`, etc. those would also be interpreted as good words.

Answer (score 13):

bash's [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) also work here:

```bsh
if [[ $program_output == @(yes|maybe|banana) ]]
then
    echo "program output is one of yes, maybe, banana"
fi
```